# Hosting the Next js project with API routes in firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, deployment, hosting, firebase-hosting

**Hosting the Next js project with API routes in firebase.**
Here the project has been developed using the Next JS- typescript.
The project structure:

Project_name
firebase.json
pages
api
login.ts
index.tsx

Hosting method follows:

- npm run build
- firebase init
- firebase deploy
- npm run build && npm run export
- firebase deploy

The out folder created for exports contains the index.html page along with other basic files and folders.

used asios method for calling the login api.

I tried calling the login api from the index.tsx file.

login.ts:

```
export default async function LoginAPI(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
 var response = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, req.body.email, req.body..password);
return res.status(200).json({message:response});
}
```

index.tsx

```
export default function Home() {
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
          const response= await axios.post('/api/login',{email:"xxxx@yyy.com",password:"xxxxxxxxx"})
alert(response.user.uid);
  }

return (
         <>
           <button onClick={()=>handleSubmit()}  >Login</>
         </>
        )
}
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Once the project is hosted, when i try to click the login button and receive the uid, it always send the html file of index inside the out folder that was created during the **npm run export**

On running locally, it works fine. But in hosted environment, it didn't.

The referred articles for solving the issue:

1. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools#integrate-nextjs
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features

From the above references, it shows that API routes is not a supported feature during the build process. If we can to do more we can only use the firebase experimental feature.

**I need a way for hosting the Next JS project with API routes in firebase.**

Comment: Can you post your firebase.json as well? You also need to have the field `rewrites` pointing to the index.html.

Comment: firebase.json has been added

Comment: Thanks. From what i understanding, you're trying to do this as a static page for the API AFTER it's built, but static page are generated on build to do API calls. I think the only way to do this on firebase is to either do SSR using `getServerSideProps` and enable firebase web frameworks. Or to handle this particular piece on the client side https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs